# css3 repeating-linear-gradient going messed in iphone

Tags: iphone, css, design-patterns, mobile

i am implementing css3 patterns in my mobile site where every browser showing background pattern nicely. but in iPhone(in chrome & in safari) pattern is getting messed up - don't know the reason can anyone help me.

thnks  in advance,

This is what I see on my IPhone:

[image: phone]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: background: repeating-linear-gradient(-49deg, #393939, #282828 4px, #393939 0px, #393939 0px );